# Lint styles into Pug files

Tags: pug, stylelint

I want to lint CSS into Pug `style.` tag raw content (CSS) and `style` attribute content (CSS).

Looks like Stylelint is a right tool to do this.

Stylelint can lint CSS strings and code blocks in `html` files, working as expected.

But if I try to do the same with `pug`, I got `Unknown word   CssSyntaxError` error.

I created a repo for testing and add tests output as comments to NPM scripts:

https://github.com/Grawl/stylelint-pug-test/commit/f4749090ab89be5da5e762a69948e072343accdf

Stylelint lints `html` using ["processor"](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configuration/#processors) to determine CSS in HTML tags and attributes. I found deprecated [`stylelint-processor-html`](https://github.com/ccbikai/stylelint-processor-html) with link to [`stylelint-processor-arbitrary-tags`](https://github.com/mapbox/stylelint-processor-arbitrary-tags) module. But it works without this processor for me (look into test repo above). Looks like HTML processor is built-in.

I cannot find Pug processor for Stylelint. Trying to find one [on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=stylelint-processor) (12 results), [on Yarn registry](https://yarnpkg.com/en/packages?q=stylelint-processor) (15 results) and [on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=stylelint-processor) (14 repositories).

Maybe I miss something? Should I write `stylelint-processor-pug` or dig into `stylelint-processor-arbitrary-tags` RegExp's?

Answer (score 1):

> Looks like Stylelint is a right tool to do this.

Yes, it is. It supports both the linting *and fixing* of CSS files and `<style>` blocks with HTML files out-of-the-box. It can also be extended to support `style.` blocks and `style=""` attributes within pug templates.

> Should I write `stylelint-processor-pug`?

You can write a `stylelint-processor-pug` and this will allow you to lint, *but not fix*, your styles within your pug templates. However, the recommended approach is to write a [PostCSS syntax](https://github.com/postcss/postcss#syntaxes), e.g. `postcss-pug`.

You can then use all PostCSS-based tools, including stylelint, to transform and analyses the styles within your pug templates. I suggest you look at both `postcss-html` and `postcss-markdown` for inspiration as these solve similar problems for their respective syntaxes.

Once you have written your custom syntax you'll need to use it in a separate stylelint task, like so:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint-styles": "stylelint '**/*.{css,html}'",
    "lint-pug-styles": "stylelint '**/*.pug' --custom-syntax postcss-pug"
  }
}
```